# "Method must have a return type"

Tags: c#

"Method must have a return type" in regards to Public Send(SerialPort serialPort1). What am I specifically missing? That is the part where I would like to begin writing to the com port. From looking at other issues online I notice that I may be missing an assembly reference or body portion for that class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TEST_Listbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new Command { DisplayText = "Part 1", CommandText = "01P00101##" });
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new Command { DisplayText = "Part 2", CommandText = "02P00102##" });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;

        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }        
    }

    public class Command
    {
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
        public string CommandText { get; set; }

        public Send(SerialPort serialPort1)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) 
            {
                var content = new List<byte>();
                content.Add(2);
                content.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CommandText));
                content.Add(3);
                byte[] buffer = content.ToArray();
                serialPort1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DisplayText;
        }
    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var command = (Command)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        if (command != null)
        {
            command.Send(serialPort1);
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: "What am I specifically missing?" The return type.

Comment: Change public Send(SerialPort serialPort1) to public void...

Comment: _Method must have a return type_ isn't clear?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines on posting _the minimal code_ needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could get an answer by simply google the error.

Comment: Here is a tip: You can highlight a compiler error (click on it) and press F1 and you should get some helpful tip on what the problem is and how to fix it. Most error messages will tell you what the actual problem is although there are exceptions to that rule when the compiler gets confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you'r Send method does not have a return type. Meaning that you don't return anything in that method. If that method shouldn't return anything, then just add void as a return type:

```
public void Send(SerialPort serialPort1)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen) 
        {
            var content = new List<byte>();
            content.Add(2);
            content.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CommandText));
            content.Add(3);
            byte[] buffer = content.ToArray();
            serialPort1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The statement that the method does not return anything has nothing to do with the lack of a return type.  It only indicates that the return type should be void.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, all methods of a class, with the exception of a Constructor/Destructor, have a return type.  Otherwise, the return type is `void`

Since your `Send()` is coded to not return anything, you're missing `void` from the method header.

From:

```
public Send(SerialPort serialPort1)
```

To:

```
public void Send(SerialPort serialPort1)
```